# Passing Variable between 2 Forms QT

Tags: c++, forms, qt

i'm a beginner so if it possible explain to me how to pass variable between 2 forms for example:
i have the first Form called : Send.ui - send.cpp - send.h
and the second form called : Receive.ui - receive.cpp - receive.h

we gonna suppose that i have a variable called age=25 in Send.cpp and a push button

i want that when i press the push button he will open the second form Receive.ui and i will have a variable in this second form age=25

that's meen if i change the variable in the Send.cpp he will be automatically changed in Receive.cpp

and thanks in advence

Comment: This is done in `Qt` using signals and slots. Emit a signal on the first form `ageChanged(int)` connecting that to a slot `ageChanged(int)` in the second form.

Answer (score 6):

For communication between objects, Qt has a mechanism called [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Here is a example of how you can use signals and slots:

In this example I will use spinboxes to visually represent the variable(age) that you mentioned.

**1. Open Receive form**

In Send, create the button that will open the receive form.

send.h

```
public:
    QPushButton *pushButton;
```

send.cpp

```
   pushButton = ui->pushButtonSend;
```

Now create a slot in mainwindow to show receive form.

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::showReceiveForm()
{
    receiveForm->show();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
private slots:
    void showReceiveForm();
```

Now connect clicked signal from the push button to the slot in mainwindow.cpp. This will call the slot function everytime the button is clicked.

```
connect(sendForm->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showReceiveForm()));
```

[image]
**2. Send Age value**

To send the age value to receive form, whenever it's value is changed in send form, connect the valueChanged signal from the [QSpinBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) in send form to a slot in receive form.

send.h:

```
public:
    QSpinBox *spinBox;
```

send.cpp

```
   spinBox = ui->spinBoxSend;
```

Slot in receive.cpp:

```
void Receive::receiveAge(int age)
{
   ui->spinBoxReceive->setValue(age);
}
```

Now connect signal and slot in mainwindow.cpp.

```
connect(sendForm->spinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),receiveForm,SLOT(receiveAge(int)));
```

[image]

In this example, I used predefined signals from QPushButton and QSpinBox, but you can create your own signals and emit them whenever.

Define custom signals in the header files:

```
signals:
    void exampleSignal(int someArgument);
```

And emit them with the "emit" keyword.

```
emit exampleSignal(somenumber);
```